# EVP keygen fuctions produce identical keys every time

Tags: c++, cryptography, openssl, rsa

I am trying to generate a unique RSA keypair using the EVP functions and then save it PEM encoded. My tests however have produced a situation where the same key pair appears to be generated each time. How can I get the keypair to be securely random? Code to reproduce below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

int main()
{
    EVP_PKEY *keypair;
    keypair = NULL;

    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_RSA, NULL);

    if(EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(ctx) <= 0)
    {

    }

    if(EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_keygen_bits(ctx, 2048) <= 0)
    {

    }

    if(EVP_PKEY_keygen(ctx, &keypair) <= 0)
    {

    }

    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);

    BIO *bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    PEM_write_bio_PUBKEY(bio, keypair);

    int pubKeyLen = BIO_pending(bio);
    unsigned char *pubKey;
    pubKey = new unsigned char[pubKeyLen];
    if(pubKey == NULL)
    {
        BIO_free_all(bio);
    }

    BIO_read(bio, pubKey, pubKeyLen);

    // Insert the NUL terminator
    pubKey[pubKeyLen-1] = '\0';

    BIO_free_all(bio);

    std::cout << std::string((const char*)pubKey, pubKeyLen);

    delete[] pubKey;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the whole base64 output strings are identical, as opposed to just starting with the same string `MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA`? There is header information that will be the same every time, but the key material after it will differ.

Comment: I think you are right...

Comment: It's not very polite if somebody posts such a possible answer as comment and you simply copy the comment into your own answer. You could at least ask the person to create his own answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Are you sure that the whole base64 output strings are identical, as opposed to just starting with the same string MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA? There is header information that will be the same every time, but the key material after it will differ.
>    –  softwariness

This is infact the case. Thanks.